# How to publish an app so that it also installs the .Net 4 (if it's not available)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, distribution, publish

I made a small application and I am ready to distribute it.

I want to know how to make an installer (or publish) so that it checks .Net 4 then installs it if its not installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [Visual Studio Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx) and include a [prerequisite of .NET 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35976/Add-Prerequisites-of-NET-Framework-in-Visual-Studi) along with your project output. You should determine whether you need [Client Profile or full-blown .NET Redistributable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx) (*typically assigned in your [application project properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398195.aspx)*).

Comment: Thanks SilverNinja. I am totally new to VS2010. I'm use to Xcode (Mac/iPhone). Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @CocoaDev - No worries...just follow this [sample walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bb4tfd.aspx) using a simple windows application. Once you get the hang of it, you can apply what you've learned to your real application.